# Whats the best CMS for Sports Club?

Tags: cms, forum, looking-for-a-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Forum Software should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25771/what-forum-software-should-i-use)

I have to renew a website for a sport club. There is some self programmed CMS in use at this time. But I need a new solution. A popular CMS that could be up to date over the next 3 or 4 years.

I took a look at Drupal 7. Not sure about whether it's easy possible to create member profiles (they should be able to edit them self), a board and team overviews. Would be cool you'll share the link of a tutorial for this needs if you have one. *Or...*

**Any suggestions for a good CMS with my needs?**

Comment: Check my answer @ http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10624/royalty-free-templates-for-website

Comment: What kind of board and team overview pages were you thinking about? Please elaborate on the functionality that you require for your new website.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an easy CMS go with Joomla. If you're looking for heavy customizability go with Drupal.

- [Creating Member Profiles Extension Tutorial in Joomla](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/community-builder-extensions/community-builder-profiles/8087)
- [Creating Member Profiles Tutorial in Drupal](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/profile)

**DRUPAL VS JOOMLA** - Key Pros and Cons

Drupal

- Rock solid & high quality platform
- Real multi-site-feature (only one installation for several sites)
- Any Kind of user groups & user permissions, OpenId compliant in Version 6
- Can run membership and community sites, not only CMS etc
- Powerful templating system. Any XHTML or CSS template can be easily converted to Drupal.
- Drupal needs a little time investment to realize all the huge possibilities of Drupal
- Clear, high quality code and API (easy to integrate with other solutions etc)
- Flexibility and no known limitations
- Many high profile sites use Drupal (e.g.: MTV UK, BBC, the Onion, Nasa, Greenpeace UK, New york observer. )

Joomla

- If you are not techy its good to start
- Easy install & setup with your mouse
- Easy learning curve
- Cannot integrate other scripts etc. to your site
- Generally you cannot create high-end sites, without investing huge amount
- No SEO out of the box, URLs are not search engine friendly.
- Server resources utilization is more compared to drupal
- Only one site per installation
- No Single Log-in to several sites
- No User groups & permissions
- More intuitive administration user interface
- Some polished modules for things like calendars, polls, etc.
- Modules cost you money

System Requirements:

- Drupal can work with MySQL and Postgres while Joomla is known to support only MySQL
- Joomla support SSL logins and SSL pages. Drupal not known to support it.

Site Management

- Drupal has free add on for Workflow management. Joomla not known to have one.
- Drupal has inbuilt Translation manager. Joomla has a Free ad on for the same
- Drupal has more   granular priviledge managment

Interoperability:

- Drupal has iCal support [Add on] , Joomla not known to have one.
- Drupal is XHTML Complaint. Joomla not known to be one.
- Drupal has excellent versioning and Audit trail which Joomla lacks

If you are still not satisfied, I suggest you read the following

- [Joomla.org's Drupal vs Joomla Comparison](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=4364)
- [Communicopia's Drupal vs Joomla Comparison](http://communicopia.com/insights/joomla-versus-drupal)

Comment: It was helpful, but it was not my question. Someone changed the title. I didn't want a Drupal vs. Joomla thread. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you describe what is the core first. I mean what are the main benefits the user will get from this website. Is it a news site? A shop? A social network? A video site?

Drupal could be a solution as it's extensible and there's already many modules available. And yes users can create and edit their own profiles in Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

I can advise JoomSport component for Joomla.

JoomSport is well structured and easy administrated. It allows to manage Teams/Individual tournaments and teams/players profiles via BE as well as via FE. There is ability to display Season table and calendar.

Website- http://joomsport.com/
Demo site- http://demo.joomsport.com/